# Multiple response messages

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to make PHP spit out several array statuses, as a response like so:

```
 elseif( $_GET["action"] == "info"){
    $username = $_GET["username"];
    $userlist = $db->query("SELECT * FROM xf_user WHERE username = '$username'");
    $fetched  = $userlist->fetch_assoc();
    $user_id = $fetched['user_id'];
    $email = $fetched['email'];
    $user_group_id = $fetched['user_group_id'];
    $secondary_group_ids = $fetched['secondary_group_ids'];
    $message_count = $fetched['message_count'];
    $reg_date = date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $fetched['register_date']);
    $warning_points = $fetched['warning_points'];
    $invite_banned = $fetched['invite_banned'];

    if($userlist){

        die(json_encode(array("status" => 200, "message" => "$user_id")));
        die(json_encode(array("status" => 200, "message2" => "$username")));
        die(json_encode(array("status" => 200, "message3" => "$email")));
        die(json_encode(array("status" => 200, "message4" => "$user_group_id")));
        die(json_encode(array("status" => 200, "message5" => "$secondary_group_ids")));
        die(json_encode(array("status" => 200, "message6" => "$message_count")));
        die(json_encode(array("status" => 200, "message7" => "$reg_date")));
        die(json_encode(array("status" => 200, "message8" => "$warning_points")));
        die(json_encode(array("status" => 200, "message9" => "$invite_banned")));
        
    } else {
        die(json_encode(array("status" => 400, "message" => "SQL error")));

    }
```

I'm outputting this to my discord bot, so i can have several fields but it throws error, any other way to output it?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Unlike James Bond you can only `die` once. The rest of those are never going to happen, they're pointless. Also in PHP `"$x"` is usually the same as `$x` so just skip the quotes. They only get in the way.

Comment: Yes, but how can i accomplish to send multiple information to my bot? and use each variable?

Comment: why not make one big json, if that don't gies, use a speratorm between the fileds as 1 big string

Comment: How you mean? can you show an example

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is a well-structured document like:

```
echo json_encode("message" => [
  "user_id" => $fetched['user_id'],
  "username" => $_GET['username'],
  ...
]
```

Where that will have proper keys. There's no need for those single-use variables, you can just link to whatever the source data is.

There's no point in putting the status in the JSON message itself, that's what [headers are for](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Comment: Ah ok, so i just call that in the python? the user id and username, is the response strings right?

Comment: Where did Python come from? This should produce a proper JSON response that something external, like Python, could consume.

Comment: Getting a error,  PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: Doing it like this:
        echo json_encode("message" => [
            "user_id" => $fetched['user_id'],
            "username" => $_GET['username'],
            "email" => $fetched['email'],
            "user_group_id" => $fetched['user_group_id'],
            "secondary_group_ids" => $fetched['secondary_group_ids'],
            "message_count" => $fetched['message_count'],

          ]